# For Azure Service Bus using .Net Core 2.0 Library, why is a handler registered by SubscriptionClient.RegisterSessionHandler not picking up messages?

Tags: .net, azureservicebus, .net-core-2.0, azure-servicebus-topics

Code registers a Session handler, but in a Topic configured with {SupportOrdering = true} (aka Enforced Ordering),  messages that do have a SessionId assigned just sit in the Topic and are not delivered.   However, they do deliver, if a regular handler is registered!

The Topic is created with "Enforced Ordering":

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Models;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
var topicParams = new SBTopic
{
 EnablePartitioning = true,
 SupportOrdering = true
};
sbMgmtClient.Topics.CreateOrUpdateAsync(resourceGroupName, namespaceName, TopicName, topicParams);
```

The Subscription Client registers a SessionMessageHandler:

```
private void Register()
{
  _subscriptionClient = new SubscriptionClient(_serviceBusConnection, _topicName, _subscriptionName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock, retryPolicy);
  var sessionHandlerOptions = new Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.SessionHandlerOptions(MessageExceptionhandler) { AutoComplete = false, MaxConcurrentSessions = 1 };
  _subscriptionClient.RegisterSessionHandler(MessageHandler, sessionHandlerOptions);
}

private async Task MessageHandler(IMessageSession session, Message msg, CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
  Console.WriteLine(msg.MessageId + " " + msg.SessionId);
  await session.CompleteAsync(msg.SystemProperties.LockToken);
}
```

Messages never deliver, they sit in the Topic Subscription undelivered.  DeliveryCount is '1', they do not go to DeadLetter.

But, if I register a regular MessageHandler, the messages deliver, and they seem to deliver in order as well.  The following results in messages delivering:

```
private void Register()
{
   var messageHandleroptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(MessageExceptionhandler) { AutoComplete = false, MaxConcurrentCalls = 1 };
  _subscriptionClient.RegisterMessageHandler(MessageHandler, messageHandleroptions);
}

private async Task MessageHandler(Message msg, CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
  Console.WriteLine(msg.MessageId + " " + msg.SessionId);
  await _subscriptionClient.CompleteAsync(msg.SystemProperties.LockToken);
}
```

I cannot find any example of SubscriptionClient with Topics using Session for Enforced Message Ordering using .Net Core 2.0, so as a corollary to this question, are there any samples of this to draw from?

Answer (score 0):

I have run your code and it works fine - I was able to send session message and receive it. It require no code changes at all. There is however tiny detail - did you *enabled sessions* when creating a subscription?

Here is how it looks in Azure Portal:

[image: Creating a session enabled subscription]

When I created a subscription like that, I was able to receive session messages. In the subscription, which does not support sessions, you will not be able to receive those messages.

[image: List of Azure Service Bus subscriptions]

NOTE: You neet to create a subscription in Azure Portal, because .Net Core Service Bus nuget package does not support creating entities yet. You can read more about it in my blog post: http://www.michalbialecki.com/2018/02/28/receiving-messages-azure-service-bus-net-core/